# Converting datetime from UICulture

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I have a SQL DB with various datetime fields stored in PST time zone.
Users from multiple regions across the world will use the DB to display data.

I need to be able to convert the SQL DB datetimes to their specific settings, which I hope to get from `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture`.

My question is, how to convert a datetime to the current user's locale in C# using the CurrentUICulture variable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ToString?

```
 DateTime date=new DateTime();
 var str = date.ToString(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);
```

Comment: So the problem is not the formatting but the actual time. Example: if the SQL datetime is 10/12/2015 14:00:00 which is in PST, when a user in the UK displays that data it should add 8 hours to it, so he should see 10/12/2015 22:00:00

Comment: look into System.TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone. It has several function that you may find usefull.